# how to use bliss view engine instead of jade in express js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

how can i use the bliss view engine instead of the usual jade engine in express js.

i already found one article here at stackoverflow, but this seems to be for the old version of express.js. i am using the 3.x version.

in particular i would like to know how i can install bliss and following to this. how do i make a project in express.js, with a different view engine then jade?

currently i use this command in my project folder:

```
 express --sessions myapp
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[consolidate.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/consolidate.js) is used as a bridge between many template engines and express. If your engine isn't supported checkout the source code. Most engines need like 15 lines of code to implement.